# what is the point of std::array function?

Tags: c++, stdarray

In the C++ `array` implementation, an `empty` method is provided. However as the implementation suggests:

```
constexpr bool
empty() const noexcept { return size() == 0; }
```

This only returns true if the size of the `array` is 0 so what is the point of it?

the typical use case for `std::array` is something like this: `std::array<type,size> a = {init here maybe};` or `a[index] = value;` afterwards.

Is there any use case where you would declare a zero length array or get it from somewhere that an empty check would be useful?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik sounds like an answer

Comment: thank you @IgorTandetnik

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Again, post your answers **in the answer section** please. The comments are for requesting clarification, not for providing the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there any use case where you would declare a zero length array or get it from somewhere that an empty check would be useful?

If you're using a template for the size of the array. for example

```
#include <array>

template <std::size_t s>
void function(std::array<int, s> const& array) {
    if (!array.empty()) {
        // other array operations ...
    }
}

int main() {
    auto empty_array = std::array<int, 0>{};
    function(empty_array);
    auto array = std::array<int, 9>{};
    function(array);
}
```

in this case, in `function` accepts arrays of different sizes so we cant be 100% sure its not empty.

edit:

additionally, the `size` and `empty` members are useful in generic code (e.g. a function that works on any container) when we have no other way to get the size (in my first example you technically can get the size from `s`). for example

```
template <class Container>
void function(Container const& array) {
    if (!array.empty()) {
        // other container operations ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the best example, as we could simply query the value of `s`. A better example would be based on `template <typename Container> void function(const Container& container) { ... }`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings true. the main benefits definitely come from having an interface thats consistent with other containers for generic code.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings ive included that point in my answer

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: "*A better example would be based on:*" The problem with that example is that you don't really take arbitrary containers in interfaces. You take iterator ranges; that in fact is the whole point of an iterator range. Functions like `back_insert_iterator` require that the container provide specific functionality that many containers don't. So you generally don't write a function that takes a container that only provides `empty`.

Comment: @NicolBolas `you don't really take arbitrary containers in interfaces. You take iterator ranges` Sometimes some people do, other times other people do something else. As cool as iterators are, the standard library container interfaces have been designed to also allow container based generic programming.

Comment: @NicolBolas I did not mean to imply it would be acceptable to take a "container" that only implements `empty`. i was meaning for `// ... ` to imply additional operations. I agree iterator ranges are generally what you want to use in this case, but its certainly not the only option. that feels like a much bigger discussion to me. regardless of the right way to design a generic container function, the `empty` methods still provide the benefit of making array usable in that code.  but i'll try to think of an example where i would prefer a container template over an iterator pair

Comment: @NicolBolas Granted. But the main point stands - `empty()` is mainly intended for use when you don't know what container you're using and so want to stick to generic, container-wide interfaces. There's probably a good real-world example of that but let's not go crazy ;)